# Olive version 0.1 does play sound for first 10-20s in a video

Tags: video

When I import an OBS or Kazam video to [Olive version 0.1](https://olivevideoeditor.org/download.php), the video's first 10 to 20 seconds do not have sound. How do I make Olive recognise that the video does have sound?

I want to use Olive 0.1, not 0.2, as it allows for auto-cut silence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some audio formats generated by default by [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) or [Kazam](https://launchpad.net/kazam) are confusing Olive 0.1 (but not Olive 0.2). If you play the video after importing it into a project, it looks like it has no sound initially.

You can use KdenLive to re-encode the video as MP4-H264-ACC. Once re-encoded, import the video to Olive 0.1; it should recognize the video has sound from the beginning.